# tikz spiral on hexagonal board

Tags: tikz-pgf

Could any of you help me with a code to render the attached figure? 
It is an hexagonal board (cells visible) showing a clockwise spiral 
starting one cell NW to the center and ending 3 cells NW to the center. 
Thank you very much, 
---J.M.S.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you enclose the TeX code that you have tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to redefine the coordinate system in TikZ. The example uses a 3D coordinate system. The middle hexagon is the origin `(0, 0, 0)`. The *x* axis goes to the right below, the *y* axis to the right above and the *z* axis to the top.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\Unit{10mm}
    \def\Num{3}
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\xdiff{cos(30) * \Unit}
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\ydiff{sin(30) * \Unit}
    \tikzset{
      x={(\xdiff, -\ydiff)},
      y={(\xdiff, \ydiff)},
      z={(0, \Unit)},
    }
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\radius{\Unit/2/cos(30)}
    \draw
      \foreach \x in {-\Num, ..., \Num} {
        \foreach \z in {
          \the\numexpr -\Num \ifnum\x>0 +\x \fi \relax,
          ...,
          \the\numexpr \Num \ifnum\x<0 +\x \fi \relax
        } {
          (\x, 0, \z)
          +(0:\radius)
          \foreach \i in {1, ..., 5} {
            -- +(60*\i:\radius)
          }
          -- cycle
        }
      }
    ;
    \draw[very thick, blue]
      (-1, 0) -- (0, 0, 1) -- (0, 1) -- (1, 0) --
      (0, 0, -1) -- (-2, 0, -1) -- (-2, 0) -- (-2, 2) --
      (0, 2) -- (2, 0) -- (0, 0, -2) -- (-3, 0, -2) --
      (-3, 0)
    ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm a fan of automatized code, but in this case it may not be worth it. I think you could just use a `plot` since it's easier to enter coordinates/node names.

The node names for each node can be "seen" by adding `label=center:{h\count\n}` to the node options. `h` stands for hexagon, while the other two variables will add numbers to make each node name unique.

Also, you can render the plot smooth or sharp depending on your needs.

### Output

**Smooth plot**
[image]

**Sharp plot**
[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\tikzset{hexa/.style={shape=regular polygon,
                      regular polygon sides=6,
                      minimum size=1cm, 
                      draw,
                      inner sep=0mm,
                      outer sep=0mm,
                      anchor=south,
                      fill=white},
        hl/.style={line width=2pt,line cap=round} 
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=5mm]

\foreach \m [count=\count] in {1,2,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,2,1}{
    \foreach \n in {1,...,\m}{
        \node at ({(\n-\m/2)*sin(30)*3},{\count*sin(60)})
        [hexa] (h\count\n) {};
    }
}

% Add [smooth] to plot to make it smooth, such as 'plot[smooth]'

\draw[hl] plot coordinates {(h82) (h92) (h83) (h63) (h52) (h71) (h91) (h112) (h93) (h53) (h32) (h61) (h101)};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```